# Auto filling parentheses and hyphen for phone number input jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, phone-number

I want to have a user's input auto fill the punctuation of a phone number to look like this (xxx) xxx-xxxx.  I have written an example jfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/x5508buz/) but it breaks when filling in the last 4 digits of the phone number.

```
$("#phone").on("change keyup paste", function () {
    var output;
    var input = $("#phone").val();
    input = input.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    var area = input.substr(0, 3);
    var pre = input.substr(3, 4);
    var tel = input.substr(6, 4);
    if (area.length < 3) {
        output = "(" + area;
    } else if (area.length == 3 && pre.length < 3) {
        output = "(" + area + ")" + " " + pre;
    } else if (area.length == 3 && pre.length == 3) {
        output = "(" + area + ")" + " " + pre + "-" + tel;
    }
    $("#phone").val(output);
});

HTMl:
<input id='phone'></input>
```

Comment: I was able to use @Felix fix, but I noticed, when someone wants to change their number, this code does not allow someone to. How do you make it a placeholder type input where they can delete their number and re-type?

Answer (score 10):

I realize this post is older but i found it quite useful and made some minor modifications to enhance it for all telephone fields and to allow for deleting characters if the user makes a mistake.

```js
$("input[type='tel']").each(function(){
  $(this).on("change keyup paste", function (e) {
    var output,
      $this = $(this),
      input = $this.val();

    if(e.keyCode != 8) {
      input = input.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
      var area = input.substr(0, 3);
      var pre = input.substr(3, 3);
      var tel = input.substr(6, 4);
      if (area.length < 3) {
        output = "(" + area;
      } else if (area.length == 3 && pre.length < 3) {
        output = "(" + area + ")" + " " + pre;
      } else if (area.length == 3 && pre.length == 3) {
        output = "(" + area + ")" + " " + pre + "-" + tel;
      }
      $this.val(output);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="tel" placeholder="(XXX) XXX-XXXX" />
```

Comment: What will be the value for pattern attribute in order to allow (xxx) xxx-xxxx. Earlier I was checking dash, so my html was, <input type="tel" pattern="^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$">

Answer (score 3):

When you're getting the pre code from the number, you're trying to get the index of 4, instead of four digits. So change that, and it should start working:

```
var pre = input.substr(3, 3);
```

If you don't want the dynamic filling, the other posted answers might be useful.

Comment: Thanks.  when I came back to it today I saw that and punched myself in the head for making a dumb mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are your friend.

```
var ok = phNum.search(/^\(?\d{3}\D*\d{3}\D*\d{4}$/);
if (ok==0) {
  var parts = phNum.match(/^\(?(\d{3})\D*(\d{3})\D*(\d{4})$/);
  output.value='('+parts[1]+') '+parts[2]+'-'+parts[3];
}
```

Accepts: 404-555-1234, 4045551234, (404) 555-1234, etc.
Returns: (404) 555-1234

Answer (score 0):

If you started to use regexp, why dont you go whole way through. Below the code that filter input value and convert it to your look.

Beware, this code only for value that contains only digits. You could block any other types via plugins or your own code. ([jquery.numeric plugin](https://github.com/SamWM/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/numeric/) is a good choice)

**jquery**

```
$(document).on('change', '.js-phone-number', function() {
  var
    $this = $(this),
    number = $this.val();

  number = number.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '($1)-$2-$3');
  $this.val(number);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are fetching variable pre as substring of length 4 and then checking it for it is less than or equal to 3. So, basically your last else if block will never be true.

Change `var pre = input.substr(3,3);`

Your code will work fine.